# Is it possible to use -Wl, -dynamic-linker to generate correct ELF linked to appropriate shared object's files?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gfortran, openmpi

I'm installing openmpi-1.4.5 from source code into gentoo with backward compatibility of GLIBC_2.11 for running under NFS (Cluster HPC) with one debian gnu/linux (squeeze) compute node.
is similar to having two systems with independent bookstores but that both can execute files in high-performance network. The idea is that both operating systems can run files via MPI.
these are the steps I performed to configure and make:

```
configure:
.././configure --prefix=/usr/local/ompi-compat --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --with-openib     CC=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -include /usr/local/include/gcc-preinclude.h

make:
make LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/spoa/usr/lib64 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/ompi-compat/lib" 2>&1 | tee make02.log
```

Later, the making stage is broken:

...

..

```
libtool: compile:  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -include /usr/local/include/gcc-preinclude.h  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../.././opal/asm -I../../opal/include -I../../orte/include -I../../ompi/include -I../../opal/mca/paffinity/linux/plpa/src/libplpa -I../../../. -I../.. -I../../.././opal/include -I../../.././orte/include -I../../.././ompi/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -finline-functions -fno-strict-aliasing -MT atomic-asm.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/atomic-asm.Tpo -c atomic-asm.S  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/atomic-asm.o
```

/usr/local/include/gcc-preinclude.h: Assembler messages:

```
/usr/local/include/gcc-preinclude.h:1: Error: invalid character '(' in mnemonic
make[2]:  [atomic-asm.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/openmpi-1.4.5/build/opal/asm'
make[1]:  [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/openmpi-1.4.5/build/opal'
make:  [all-recursive] Error 1
```

There are troubles about module asm because i use one include c adaptation for exclude memcpy@2_2_5 symbols from header /usr/local/include/gcc-preinclude.h:

```
__asm__(".symver memcpy,memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5");
```

I fixed this situation into folder add --tag=CC and cut "-include /usr/local/include/gcc-preinclude.h" from x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc compiler  :

```
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC --mode=compile x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../.././opal/asm -I../../opal/include -I../../orte/include -I../../ompi/include -I../../opal/mca/paffinity/linux/plpa/src/libplpa   -I../../../. -I../.. -I../../.././opal/include -I../../.././orte/include -I../../.././ompi/include    -O3 -DNDEBUG -finline-functions -fno-strict-aliasing -MT atomic-asm.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o atomic-asm.lo atomic-asm.S &&mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
```

Compile with this line into opal/asm/ folder is great!

Back to main build folder and continue with compilation:

```
make LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/spoa/usr/lib64 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/ompi-compat/lib" 2>&1 | tee make02.log
```

Few minutes after the compilation is effective.

But when i test some executable for run, appear as "Segmentation fault":

```
cd opal/tools/wrappers/.libs

.libs # ./opal_wrapper 
Segmentation fault
```

So with all executables...

```
Now, veryfing the Shared Library path linking to ELF File:
ldd opal_wrapper 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3ffff000)
libopen-pal.so.0 => /usr/local/ompi-compat/lib/libopen-pal.so.0 (0x00002b8ea8239000)
libdl.so.2 => /spoa/usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b8ea8493000)
libnsl.so.1 => /spoa/usr/lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00002b8ea8697000)
libutil.so.1 => /spoa/usr/lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00002b8ea88af000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b8ea8ad5000)
libpthread.so.0 => /spoa/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b8ea8d56000)
libc.so.6 => /spoa/usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b8ea8f72000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b8ea8017000)
```

There are shared object files linked with -rpath. I use the main original shared objects shipped with debian "squeeze" into /spoa/usr/lib64 folder and linking OK! but i think that fail is originate in the linking to original gentoo dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86_64.so.2

```
There is my debian "squeeze" main toolchain shared objects:
ls  /spoa/usr/lib64/
ld-2.11.3.so          libdl.so.2            libnsl-2.11.3.so      libstdc++.so.6.0.13        libz.so.1.2.3.4
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  libgcc_s.so           libnsl.so.1           libutil-2.11.3.so
libc-2.11.3.so        libgcc_s.so.1         libpthread-2.11.3.so  libutil.so.1
libc.so.6             libgfortran.so.3.0.0  libpthread.so.0       libz.so
libdl-2.11.3.so       libm.so               libstdc++.so.6        libz.so.1
```

If i manually change the linker for this executable run into gentoo & debian (via NFS) and finally running:

```
/bin/sh ../../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -include    /usr/local/include/gcc-preinclude.h  -O3 -DNDEBUG -finline-functions -fno-strict-aliasing -pthread -fvisibility=hidden  -L/spoa/usr/lib64 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/spoa/usr/lib64 -o opal_wrapper opal_wrapper.o ../../../opal/libopen-pal.la -lnsl -lutil  -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/ompi-compat/lib -Wl,-dynamic-linker /spoa/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Result:

```
libtool: link: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -include /usr/local/include/gcc-preinclude.h -O3     -DNDEBUG -finline-functions -fno-strict-aliasing -pthread -fvisibility=hidden -Wl,-rpath -    Wl,/spoa/usr/lib64 -o .libs/opal_wrapper opal_wrapper.o -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/ompi-    compat/lib -Wl,-dynamic-linker /spoa/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  -L/spoa/usr/lib64     ../../../opal/.libs/libopen-pal.so -ldl -lnsl -lutil -lm -pthread
```

and ldd show correctly the appropiate linker:

```
wrappers ldd .libs/opal_wrapper 

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc75a7000)
libopen-pal.so.0 => /usr/local/ompi-compat/lib/libopen-pal.so.0 (0x00002b396dd38000)
libdl.so.2 => /spoa/usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b396df91000)
libnsl.so.1 => /spoa/usr/lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00002b396e196000)
libutil.so.1 => /spoa/usr/lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00002b396e3ae000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b396e5d3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /spoa/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b396e855000)
libc.so.6 => /spoa/usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b396ea71000)
/spoa/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b396db18000)
```

My Question is **whether it is possible to use -Wl, -dynamic-linker to generate correct ELF linked to appropriate shared object's files?**

Running:
./opal_wrapper
Cannot open configuration file /usr/local/ompi-compat/share/openmpi/opal_wrapper-wrapper-data.txt
Error parsing data file opal_wrapper: Not found

Some of My Host Info:

```
hostname = master
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.4.5-gentoo
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Mon Jul 23 21:35:06 UTC 2012
```